# Проверка на наличие подстроки с помощью std::regex

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++

Здравствуйте.
С помощью регулярных выражений я пытаюсь проверить наличие подстроки. Для этого пишу такой код:

```
std::regex search(searchOption, std::regex::icase);
if(regex_search(currentBook, search))return true;
else return false;

//searchOption - подстрока, которую нужно найти

//currentBook - строка, где нужно искать
```

Но если у меня searchOption будет равен "C++", то у меня вылетит эксепшн. Можно ли это как-то исправить?

Comment: @devnikor, каким компилятором пользуетесь?

В g++ регэкспы не до конца реализованы. Там лучше использовать сишные regcomp()/regexec() (см. man 7 regex и man 3 regex).

Но, если Вы ищете вхождение подстроки (без метасимволов и проч.), то string.find() или strstr/strcasestr более эффективно.

Comment: Использую vc11. Просто мне нужен был case insensitive поиск. А string::find + std::transform = много кода. Хотелось покомпактней написать.

Comment: @devnicor, как там в M$ обстоят дела, не знаю. 

Но strcasestr надеюсь работает (возвращает адрес найденной подстрки или NULL). IMHO компактно. Кстати, для работы с русским не забудьте вызвать setlocale().

Comment: Для нахождения подстроки нашёл boost::algorithm::contains. Компактней некуда :)

А с русским не работаю, так как, что бы я ни пробовал, ничего не получается. Но это не беда

Comment: Переходите в линукс, может и с русским получится.

Comment: Я и сам хочу, вот только с драйверами на видео проблема. Когда ставлю проприетарные, система рушится вся. А с опенсурсными дровами у меня ноут греется. Intel/AMD же.

Comment: Отличная идея, но всё равно хочется полностью отказаться от Windows, так как видеть больше не могу все эти плоские квадратики. Да и хочется новых ощущений

Comment: @avp

      Переходите в линукс, может и с русским получится.

И `%-20s` в printf будет работать, как старые добрые времена... (Ну в c++ это cout.width(20) вроде). Не верю

Comment: @alexlz, а что такое в `printf` с `%-20s`?

Я даже разволновался, удалил предыдущий коммент:

    Попробуйте в виртуалке (например, VirtualBox).

(лимит-с!!!), не поленился, набрал какой-то тестик с несколькими `%-20s` и ничего необычного не увидел.

Выравнивает по левому краю поля, строки длиннее 20 не обрезает. А Вы чего-то другого ожидали?

Comment: @avp

    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      printf("%20s:\n12345678901234567890:\n", "абракадабра");
      return 0;
    }

    абракадабра:
    12345678901234567890:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Но если у меня searchOption будет
> равен "C++", то у меня вылетит
> эксепшн.

что за бред? зачем вы посылаете в `std::regex` подстроку? *(вот вам и ошибка)*

туда надо посылать регулярное выражение! [тык 1](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/), [тык 2](http://habrahabr.ru/post/64226/)

а чтобы найти "C++" или "app" используйте [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/)/ [search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search/)

 и т.п.

если же вам важны разделители то сначала разберитесь в том как правильно составлять регулярки!

p.s. ну если вам надо найти "app" то ищите " app "

---

---

---

**UPD**

ну раз можно отправить и саму строку то значит ругается на "++"

если это так, то надо плюсы экранировать `\\`

Comment: Да не, можно послать и строку, которую надо найти: 
[Вот][1]


  [1]: http://softwareramblings.com/2008/07/regular-expressions-in-c.html